# How can I be sure I've removed the old thermal grease thoroughly?

Tags: cooling, thermal-paste

How can you be sure that you've removed the old thermal grease thoroughly?

I've been rubbing old thermal grease from the heat sink for a day now with isopropyl, and still a black residue appears on the cotton balls.

Does this mean I have removed all of the thermal grease from the heatsink?

[image]

Comment: Ahh, thermal grease thoroughly - that's what OP mean! OK, I see ...

Comment: The black marks may actually be aluminium oxidation from the rubbing alcohol, you're rubbing off aluminum. ;)  If you can't see any thermal compound on the heatsink, then you've pretty much removed it all.

Comment: Have I done too much harm this way?

Comment: Most likely not, you'd have to rub for quite awhile to remove enough aluminum to make a noticeable difference.  Can you post a picture of the bottom of your heat sink?

Answer (score 1):

Black is the aluminum coming off, it will do that forever as long as you want to rub on it. Stop cleaning and put some thermal paste on it.